# Jpa repository special words like "and' , "or" not working

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a simple UserRepository which extends JpaRepository.

I am trying to find a user for a given username and password.

Here is my repository class

```
    public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {

        public Optional<User> findByusUnameAndusPassword(String username, String password);
    }
```

Here is my entity class

```
    public class User implements java.io.Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "us_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private int usId;

    @Column(name = "us_uname", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String usUname;

    @Column(name = "us_password", nullable = false, length = 100)
    private String usPassword;
 }
```

This is the error that I am getting

```
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.Optional com.example.repository.UserRepository.findByusUnameAndusPaasword(java.lang.String,boolean)! No property andusPassword found for type String! Traversed path: User.usUname.
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:178) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:101) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1821) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1266) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:260) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:623) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:611) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.config.DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener.onApplicationEvent(DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener.java:51) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.config.DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener.onApplicationEvent(DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener.java:36) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:403) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:360) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:897) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:553) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:120) [spring-boot-test-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99) [spring-test-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124) [spring-test-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:123) [spring-test-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:190) [spring-test-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:132) [spring-test-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:244) [spring-test-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.postProcessTestInstance(SpringExtension.java:98) [spring-test-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$5(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:341) [junit-jupiter-engine-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.executeAndMaskThrowable(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:346) [junit-jupiter-engine-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$6(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:341) [junit-jupiter-engine-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `findByUsUnameAndUsPassword` instead of `findByusUnameAndusPassword`.

```
Optional<User> findByUsUnameAndUsPassword(String username, String password);
```